# How to make the merged cells group its corresponding cells from another column?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, hashmap, apache-poi

There are 2 columns, Key and Sentence columns. Now, in Key Column, some cells are merged.
While, in the Sentence column, they are all in separate cells.

In the example below, k1 and k5 are mergd cells.

```
    | Key  | Sentence |
    | ---- | -------- |
    |  k1  |    s1    |
    |      |    s2    |
    |      |    s3    |
    |  k2  |    s4    |
    |  k3  |    s5    |
    |  k4  |    s6    |
    |  k5  |    s7    |
    |      |    s8    |
    |  k6  |    s9    |
```

I need the Key and Sentence to become Key-Pair values for my xml file which I already have an idea on the xml part.

I know we can use HashMap or LinkedHashMap for the key-value pairs. However, I find it hard to combine the cells of Sentence column as 1 cell(value) with respect to the key.

How can we group the cells in Sentence column to match with their corresponding cell in Key column?

I can read the excel file through POI. I'm just stuck with this part. I've also searched for answers similar to my problem but I could only find answers that aren't related but somehow gave me ideas.

[sample image of excel problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNRpT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For merged cells the cell content is placed in first (top-left) cell of the merged region. All other merged cells are empty. So the main logic here is:

If the key gotten from key column is not empty, then a new key had occurred. Else the sentences got from sentence column belong to the last got key.

If key column and sentence column as well as first row and last row is known, then following would work:

Sheet given:

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

class ReadExcelKeySentence {

 static Map<String, List<String>> getKeysAndSentences(Sheet sheet, DataFormatter formatter, FormulaEvaluator evaluator, 
                                   int keyColumn, int sentenceColumn, int firstRow, int lastRow) {

  Map<String, List<String>> keysAndSentences = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
  List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();

  Row row; 
  Cell cell;
  String key;
  String sentence;
  for (int r = firstRow; r <= lastRow; r++) {
   row = sheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.getCell(keyColumn); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(keyColumn);
   key = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
   cell = row.getCell(sentenceColumn); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(sentenceColumn);
   sentence = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
   if (!"".equals(key)) {
    sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    sentences.add(sentence);
    keysAndSentences.put(key, sentences);
   } else {
    sentences.add(sentence);
   }
  }

  return keysAndSentences;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xls"));
  DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator =  workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Map<String, List<String>> keysAndSentences = getKeysAndSentences(sheet, formatter, evaluator, 1, 2, 1, 9);

  System.out.println(keysAndSentences);

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Produces:

```
{k1=[s1, s2, s3], k2=[s4], k3=[s5], k4=[s6], k5=[s7, s8], k6=[s9]}
```

Comment: I just like to ask 3 more questions: 1. if the cell is null, why use createCell?  2. Why do we need to use a formula evaluator? 3. What does (!"".equals) mean? Does it mean "not string" or "not empty"?

Comment: @alfrosz: 1. if the cell is null, why use createCell?; Here this is not really needed. `DataFormatter` handles `null` cells properly. But in general it avoids `NullPointerException` when `cell` gets used further. 2. Why do we need to use a formula evaluator?: It is needed when cells in key or sentence columns contain formulas. For ex. when key or sentence values are formula results instead of literals. 3. What does (!"".equals) mean?: `!`= not `""` empty string `equals` `key`. In other words: The `key` is not an empty string.

Comment: I'll keep these in mind. Thank you for your explanations.